# Can fullcalendar be staticly rendered with less Javascript?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to render a static fullcalendar? No drag & drop, no clickable events, etc? I'd like to exclude some Javascript if possible.

Comment: you can quite easily change the settings to make it so that certain actions are impossible for the user (e.g. dragging, selecting, clicking), meaning the calendar is basically static, but removing the actual code which provides the functionality to make those features possible would require you to alter the fullCalendar source code (or alter the final .js file after you download it) - fullCalendar is provided as a single .js file, so there's no simple way to entirely remove sections of code. You'd need to modify the JS yourself and then re-test to ensure you hadn't broken it.

Comment: @ADyson That's what I figured, but I wanted to be sure. Thank you!